How to nearest neighbor in Pixi.js?
I found in the docs there's a change like this:

SCALE_MODES replaced with ScaleMode strings
SCALE_MODES.NEAREST -> 'nearest',
SCALE_MODES.LINEAR -> 'linear',

So, it is supported. But I don't see any examples how to actually use ScaleMode, as nearest-neightboar, to properly render Pixel-Art graphics in PixiJS. Official Docs don't say anything about it:


Seems to be the solution for pixi.js@8.1.0:
import { TextureStyle } from 'pixi.js';

TextureStyle.defaultOptions.scaleMode = 'nearest';

After that, creating new textures automatically applies nearest-neightbor to them.
